# supervisord holds port after main program termination

Tags: process, c, supervisord

I am spawning supervisord  from a C program through system() in the foreground which starts 2 additional threads in the foreground.

Normally if everything goes well this is not an issue, however if my main program crashes, supervisord crawls on it's port:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9777            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       42478       7250/python
```

Normally it has nothing to do with it, supervisord should not even touch the network... The C program using that port only for telnet communication.

Did anyone run into this issue?

Well then at next start of course my C program would not start because something is listening on that port...

If I cannot find a solution for this I will have to forcekill all supervisord processes at program start.